# Can't install BGSlibrary(pybgs) library from pypi for python using visual studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, pypi

I have been trying for 3 days to install this [library](https://pypi.org/project/pybgs/#description). It uses CMake and i can't understand how to add OpenCV path within visual studio. I have tried a lot of things like:
1.use CMake-GUI to generate .sln file then build there is also an error.
2.try to add through cmd with CMake but there I face another error.

I believe there is a simple way of directly doing it through visual studio which I am unfamiliar of and can't seem to find it. If someone is kind enough to tell me in simple way how to install library using visual studio python 3.6.

Here is the error I get in VS 2017 after I try to install pybgs library through pip install pybgs

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pybgs
Failed to build pybgs
Installing collected packages: pybgs
    Running setup.py install for pybgs: started
    Running setup.py install for pybgs: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    

    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:113 (find_package):
    By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
    asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
    CMake did not find one.

    Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
    of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake
```

Comment: I am unsure that you may add OpenCV path when install the project via `pip`. However, you may build the project from the sources using this tutorial: https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary/wiki/Compiling-BGSLibrary-with-OpenCV-3.x-and-Visual-Studio-2015-from-CMAKE.

Comment: I have tried this tutorial but When I try to build .sln file there is an error like cv::scale cant change.

Comment: Looks like a problem in the project you are building (`bgslibrary`). Since installing the library via `pip` also implies building the project, you will likely face with the same error. Report this error to project's developers. Or you may ask another question on Stack Overflow about this problem.